# How do I add data to a column only if a certain value exists in previous column using Python and Faker?

Tags: python, pandas, function, faker

I'm pretty new to Python and not sure what to even google for this. What I am trying to do is create a Pandas DataFrame that is filled with fake data by using Faker. The problem I am having is each column is generating fake data in a silo. I want to be able to have fake data created based on something that exists in a prior column.

So in my example below, I have `pc_type ["PC", "Apple]` From there I have the operating system and the options are Windows 10, Windows 11, and MacOS. Now I want only where `pc_type = "Apple"` to have the columns fill with the value of MacOS. Then for everything that is type PC, it's 50% Windows 10 and 50% Windows 11.

How would I write this code so that in the function body I can make that distinction clear and the results will reflect that?

```
from faker import Faker
from faker.providers import BaseProvider, DynamicProvider
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import random

pc_type = ['PC', 'Apple']
fake = Faker()


def create_data(x):
    project_data = {}
    for i in range(0, x):
        project_data[i] = {}
        project_data[i]['Name'] = fake.name()
        project_data[i]['PC Type'] = fake.random_element(pc_type)
        project_data[i]['With Windows 10'] = fake.boolean(chance_of_getting_true=25)
        project_data[i]['With Windows 11 '] = fake.boolean(chance_of_getting_true=25)
        project_data[i]['With MacOS'] = fake.boolean(chance_of_getting_true=50)

    return project_data


df = pd.DataFrame(create_data(10)).transpose()
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd slightly change the approach and generate a column `OS`. This column you can then transform into `With MacOS` etc. if needed.

With this approach its easier to get the 0.5 / 0.5 split within Windows right:

```py
from faker import Faker
from faker.providers import BaseProvider, DynamicProvider
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import random
from collections import OrderedDict

pc_type = ['PC', 'Apple']
wos_type = OrderedDict([('With Windows 10', 0.5), ('With Windows 11', 0.5)])
fake = Faker()

def create_data(x):
    project_data = {}
    for i in range(x):
        project_data[i] = {}
        project_data[i]['Name'] = fake.name()
        project_data[i]['PC Type'] = fake.random_element(pc_type)
        if project_data[i]['PC Type'] == 'PC':
            project_data[i]['OS'] = fake.random_element(elements = wos_type)
        else:
            project_data[i]['OS'] = 'MacOS'

    return project_data


df = pd.DataFrame(create_data(10)).transpose()
df
```

Output

```py
                     Name PC Type               OS
0         Nicholas Walker   Apple            MacOS
1               Eric Hull      PC  With Windows 10
2       Veronica Gonzales      PC  With Windows 11
3  Mrs. Krista Richardson   Apple            MacOS
4              Anne Craig      PC  With Windows 10
5            Joseph Hayes      PC  With Windows 10
6             Mary Nelson   Apple            MacOS
7               Jill Hunt   Apple            MacOS
8             Mark Taylor      PC  With Windows 11
9           Kyle Thompson      PC  With Windows 10
```

Answer (score 1):

To have coherent values, you can use something like:

```
from faker import Faker
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def create_data(x):
    pc_type = ['PC', 'Apple']
    fake = Faker()
    data = {'Name': [fake.name() for _ in range(x)],
            'PC Type': np.random.choice(pc_type, x)}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['With MacOS'] = df['PC Type'] == 'Apple'

    pc = df['PC Type'] == 'PC'
    w10 = np.random.choice([True, False], len(df), p=(0.5, 0.5))
    df['With Windows 10'] = pc & w10
    df['With Windows 11'] = pc & ~w10

    return df

df = create_data(10)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                Name PC Type  With MacOS  With Windows 10  With Windows 11
0     Charles Dawson      PC       False             True            False
1  Patricia Bautista      PC       False            False             True
2         Ruth Clark      PC       False             True            False
3       Justin Lopez      PC       False             True            False
4      Grace Russell      PC       False             True            False
5         Grant Moss      PC       False             True            False
6           Tracy Ho   Apple        True            False            False
7    Connie Mitchell   Apple        True            False            False
8  Catherine Nichols   Apple        True            False            False
9   Nathaniel Bryant      PC       False            False             True
```